Trying booting into Debian or Ubuntu on MacBook Air shows black screen
I'm trying to install Ubuntu or Debian on a MacBookAir ( as dual-boot or as a single, I don't care that much).
Everytime I select "EFI Boot", laptop goes into the black screen. After a while I hear it is processing something, but it is still black screen.
Below are the specifications and steps that I did:
MacBook Air8.1
Intel Core i5
In Recovery Mode, under Utilities > Startup Security Utility I allowed "External Boot: Allow booting from external or removable media". All secure boots are disabled.
I tried following images (and I checked shasum, they are correct)
debian-12.8.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso
debian-12.8.0-amd64-netinst.iso
lubuntu-24.10-desktop-amd64.iso

Created a Bootable USB using balenaEtcher.
MacBook and hold option to launch the boot menu.
Select "EFI Boot".
And then the screen goes black.
I tried to press "E", "ESC" or "Shift" immediately after selecting "EFI Boot" hoping to get to get GRUB bootloader menu, but none of it worked.
What should I do to install debian or ubuntu? What am I doing wrong?
Thank you a lot for the support and advice!

FYI, we cannot help you with Debian,  Debian is offtopic here.

Download the Ubuntu 24.04 iso: https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?version=24.04.1&architecture=amd64&lts=true, burn the iso to a USB of at least 16 gigs. Start your computer. Start a Live session. After the upload is complete, open a terminal. In it, run: sudo inxi -F Copy the output, edit your post, and paste it into it

Your question would have been on-topic if asked on Stack Exchange Unix & Linux, however the Debian detail is off-topic on this Ubuntu only site. Your details with Lubuntu don't show any checks being performed; ie. ISO validation (ensuring checksum was correct) or validation of ISO write to media (no mention of any checks performed - this step is where i experience most issues). This won't rule out graphics issues but I'd try safe graphics as per Lubuntu manual. I'm not familiar with mac & EFI boot; but 24.10 media will boot/install on uEFI or legacy if ISO written correctly.
